# Reason for slow Adobe AIR app performance?

Tags: performance, sqlite, air

I am trying to debug a strange problem with Windows XP (SP3) Adobe AIR performance.  Our app syncs data from a remote server to a local SQLite database, and on certain machines, this process takes   15 minutes or more. It should take, at most, a few minutes.  We've done enough investigating to come to the conclusion that is definitely related to specific machines, but we're not sure if it's performance with AIR, or SQLite, or something else.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was adding transactions around our sql inserts.  Sort of counterintuitive since transactions usually slow down SQL performance, but with sqlite I guess it prevents you from having to write to disk on every insert.

Answer (score 0):

different processes but i'm having almost same trouble i guess. an air application with a fixed video player playing its playlist at repeat mode. same time a few or more socket connections working on the foreground to gather and show live data from single remote server. works smoothly on win machines (even on slower ones) but flickering badly on linux which installed to a decent machine (tested on ubuntu only).

any more info about what you have done to solve your problem ?